# AngularJS nested directive with ng-include

Tags: directive, angular-directive

I have problem with nested directive in ng-include. Here's the situation:
I have template in slim like this:

```
ng-include src="includePath" quick-edit=""
```

This includes file with template which has nested ng-includes, code:

```
.container ng-init="initialize()" style="padding:20px 50px"
  .row
    .col-xs-6.col-xs-offset-3
      img ng-src="{{shop.logo}}"
  .row ng-repeat="section in mainPageSections"
    section 
      ng-include src="section.source"
```

Everything works fine but in first ng-include I have directive quick-edit which looks:

```
'use strict'
app = angular.module('saasPlatform')

app.directive 'quickEdit', ['$rootScope', '$compile', ($rootScope, $compile) ->
restrict: 'A'
link: (scope, element, attrs) ->

  $rootScope.$on '$includeContentLoaded', (event, templateName) ->
    $sections = element.find('.row > section')
    for item in $sections
      $section = angular.element item
      $section.attr('editable','')
      $section.attr('editable-type','section')
    return
    element.html $compile(element.contents())(scope)
]

## editable directive ##

app.directive 'editable', [()->
  restrict: 'A'
  link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
    console.log 'editable'
]
```

Problem is that directive editable doesn't work.